# Which superhero wears red, white, and blue, and works as a furniture mover?

Tags: story-identification, character-identification

I'm searching for a comic super hero, that is not from DC or Marvel universe.

I once read a collection book (in German) some 20+ years ago. It was not originally German, but translated.

The hero in question is male, wears as red, white and blue costume (at least in my memory), works as a furniture mover, has some financial trouble, and is member of a super hero group of 4 maybe 5 members.

If I remember correctly the hero has the suffix '-man' in his alter ego name. I don't know if 'star' was a part of his name, or part of the names of the other members, or part of the name of the hero group. But I'm 50% sure, 'star' was part of one of the aforementioned.

He has superior physical strength, but couldn't fly (maybe).

The hero group had male and female members.

The hero was maybe like a copy of Captain America without the shield.

Comment: Latest edit shouldn't be an edit, it should be a comment.

Comment: Hmmm, red, white, and blue furniture movers.  Did they also make [money for nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jb5tc.png) and their chicks for free?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is [The Shield](https://www.writeups.org/shield-higgins-red-circle-archie-comics/), AKA Bill Higgins.

He's a removal man by trade, dresses like Captain America, is a member of the 'Mighty Crusaders' team and wasn't originally a Marvel or DC character (he appeared in comics published by Archie Comics).

[image]

Comment: It was this story, which I read: https://www.firstcomicsnews.com/bingbackthecomback-mighty-crusaders-4/

Comment: OK, I'm finding it very funny that the character that @yunzen described as being "a copy of Captain America without the shield" is _called_ The Shield.

Comment: The Shield actually predates Captain America: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shield_(Archie_Comics)

Comment: @Robobunny - Ooh yes. By almost a whole year. Good find.